# UICollectionView Custom sorting in NSFetchResultController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionview` with `NSFetchResultController`. I am using https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout for drag and drop to reorder cells. 
While rearranging the cells, I have observed that duplicate cells appear. This issue gets corrected when I scroll.

Can someone pls help me out on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you update core data such that the sort descriptor of the FRC's request's will sort so that the new order is maintained?